# Print Button in ASPX page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have quick question. I have a table in ASPX page and I am trying to make my Print functionality work. I would like to Print particular row when a row is selected and print whole table when now row is selected. i am able to make selected row work. but i am not able print whole table when no row is selected. Is it okay to have same print button to do both functionalities or do i need to use different button. thank you

```js
function PrintPage() {

        //var printContent = document.getElementById('<= SessionNotes.ClientID %>');
       var printContent = document.getElementById('printsessionNote');
    
       var printWindow = window.open("Selected Row", "Print Panel", 'left=50000,top=50000,width=0,height=0');

       printWindow.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);

       printWindow.document.close();

       printWindow.focus();

       printWindow.print();
       return false;

    }
    function Divprint(category,date,starttime,endtime,totaltime,staff,note)
        {
            $('#lblDateval').html(date);
            $('#lblCategoryval').html(category);
            $('#lblstarttimeal').html(starttime);
            $('#lblEndtimeal').html(endtime);
            $('#lblTotaltimeal').html(totaltime);
            $('#lblstaffphysicianal').html(staff);
            $('#lblnote').html(note);
            return false;
        }
```

```html
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hdn_FromID" runat="server" Value="" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdn_ToId" runat="server" Value="" />
        
<div id="printsessionNote" runat="server">
            <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>Date</td>
                    <td>Category</td>
                    <td>Start Time</td>
                    <td>End Time</td>
                    <td>Total Time</td>
                    <td>Staf/Physician</td>
                    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label id="lblDateval"></label></td>
                    <td><label id="lblCategoryval"></label></td>
                    <td><label id="lblstarttimeal"></label></td>
                    <td><label id="lblEndtimeal"></label></td>
                    <td><label id="lblTotaltimeal"></label></td>
                    <td><label id="lblstaffphysicianal"></label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6">
                        Note : <label id="lblnote"></label>
                       
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div>

                  <asp:Button ID="btnprintpatientlist" runat="server" Text="Print" OnClientClick=" javascript:return PrintPage();"
            BackColor="#FFCB05" Width="100px" Height="30" BorderWidth="0" />
                  <asp:Button ID="btndownloadpdf" runat="server" Text="Download" BackColor="#FFCB05" Width="100px" Height="30" BorderWidth="0" OnClick="btnExport_Click"/> 
              </div>
                <p hidden="hidden" class="ses-pls">Please Select the session note(s) to print or select 'Print' to 'Print all'</p>
              
            </div>
```

Comment: In what way is your code not working?  Are you trying to solve the printing problem, or asking whether it's a good user experience to have one button vs. two?  It's not really clear what you're asking from us.

Comment: Hi David. I am trying to make my code work at same time, I am asking is it a good approach have same button for two functionalities.